# Unexpected result when writing a Unicode(UTF-8) text to file

Tags: java

I have problem when writing a Unicode(UTF-8) text to file with java.
I want writ some text in other language (Persian) to file in java, but i receive Unexpected result after run my app.

```
 File file = new File(outputFileName);
 FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
 String encoding = "UTF-8";
 OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(f,encoding);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

 StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
 row.append("Some text in English language");
 // in below code it should be  4 space before علی
 row.append("    علی");  
 // in below code it should be 6 space before علی یاری 
 row.append("      علی یاری");
 bw.write(row.toString());
 bw.flush(); bw.close();
```

[image]

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't persian normally written right to left, just as the program is doing? First word to the right, second word to the left?

Comment: A more minimal code sample for this question: `System.out.print("["); System.out.print(" ل " ); System.out.print(" ی "); System.out.print("]");` - and the output is `[ ل  ی ]`

Comment: @joachim-isaksson  output is left to right and i want write some Persian text after English text

Answer (score -1):

The output is what is expected according to the [Unicode bidirectional algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/). The entire Persian text is rendered right-to-left. If you want the individual words to be laid out left-to-right, then you need to insert a strongly left-to-right character between the two Persian words. There's a special character for this: LEFT TO RIGHT MARK (U+200e). This modification to your code should produce the correct output:

```
row.append("Some text in English language");
row.append("    علی");
row.append('\u200e');
row.append("      علی یاری");
```

Comment: Actually, I think this is related to the right-to-left override which is hidden in the text.

Comment: @Makoto - There's a RLO in the text? I don't see it in OP's source.